# how to prove that $I(\alpha)=\iint_{D_\alpha}x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ has zero(s)?

Tags: calculus, integration

$I(\alpha)=\iint_{D_\alpha}x\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}-y\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y$ has zero(s),
where $D(\alpha): (x-2\cos\alpha)^2+(y-2\sin\alpha)^2\leqslant1$, and $f$ is continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R^2}$

---

I made a few attempts:

put $\boldsymbol{r}=(x-2\cos\alpha,y-2\sin\alpha)$ and $\theta=\arctan\frac{y-2\sin\alpha}{x-2\cos\alpha}$, and $I(\alpha)$ can be simplified as $I(\alpha)=2\int_{0}^{1}r\mathrm{d}r\int_0^{2\pi}\mathrm{d}\theta[\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\sin(\theta-\alpha)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}\frac{\cos(\theta-\alpha)}{r}]$. Then can I say that $I(\alpha)=-I(\alpha+\pi)$? (or in other words $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial\theta}$ inside the integral are independent of $\alpha$?) If so then the problem is solved.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you try parameterizating the integral? Or using polar coordinates?

Comment: @Cameron i tried polar coordinates (as shown above), but i'm not sure whether it's correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First notice that $\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\Bigg[f\left(r\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)+2\sin(\alpha)\right)\Bigg]$ equals the following expression: $$r\cos(\theta)f_y\left(r\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)+2\sin(\alpha)\right)-r\sin(\theta)f_x\left(r\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)+2\sin(\alpha)\right)$$ Also notice $\frac{\partial}{\partial \alpha}\Bigg[f\left(r\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)+2\sin(\alpha)\right)\Bigg]$ equals the following: $$2\cos(\alpha)f_y\left(r\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)+2\sin(\alpha)\right)-2\sin(\alpha)f_x\left(r\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)+2\sin(\alpha)\right)$$

So if we enforce the substitution $(x,y)\mapsto \left(r\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)+2\sin(\alpha)\right)$ we obtain the following expression for $I(\alpha)$: $$\int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}r \frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\Bigg[f\left(r\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)+2\sin(\alpha)\right)\Bigg]\mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}r + \int_0^1\int_0^{2\pi}r\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\Bigg[f\left(r\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)+2\sin(\alpha)\right)\Bigg]\mathrm{d}\theta\mathrm{d}r$$ The first integral vanishes by direct evaluation. By Leibniz's rule, $$I(\alpha)=\frac{d}{d\alpha}\int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}rf\left(r\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)+2\sin(\alpha)\right)\mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}r$$ Because $\alpha \mapsto \int_0^1 \int_0^{2\pi}rf\left(r\cos(\theta)+2\cos(\alpha),r\sin(\theta)+2\sin(\alpha)\right)\mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}r$ is periodic and differentiable, its derivative must vanish at some input by Rolle's Theorem concluding the result.